# docker-compose build args not passing to Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  ei:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        NODE_VERSION: 8
        HELLO: 5
```

Dockerfile:

```
ARG NODE_VERSION
ARG HELLO

FROM node:$NODE_VERSION

RUN echo "-> $HELLO"
RUN echo "-> $NODE_VERSION"
```

Results in:

```
km@Karls-MBP ~/dev/ve (km/ref) $ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build --no-cache
vertica uses an image, skipping
Building ei
Step 1/14 : ARG NODE_VERSION
Step 2/14 : ARG HELLO
Step 3/14 : FROM node:$NODE_VERSION
 ---> e63de54eee16
Step 4/14 : RUN echo "-> $HELLO"
 ---> Running in e93d89e15913
-> 
Removing intermediate container e93d89e15913
 ---> c305b277291c
Step 5/14 : RUN echo "-> $NODE_VERSION"
 ---> Running in 39e8e656c0bd
-> 8
```

I'm scratching my head as to why this isn't working. If I change the node version number the number changes.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The defined arguments on the compose file are available on the Dockerfile but only before and on the `FROM`. After the `FROM` the arguments are not available:

> An `ARG` declared before a `FROM` is outside of a build stage, so it can't be used in any instruction after a `FROM`. - [*from docker docs*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact)

**Why is the argument `NODE_VERSION` working?**
The argument `NODE_VERSION` isn't working after the `FROM`. The argument is only used on the `FROM` (`FROM node:8`). After `FROM` there is a [environment variable of the image](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/25f26146ac5b9f74add731b0b078e34411ae5831/8/Dockerfile#L24) with the same name. So you echo the environment variable of the image instead of the argument of your compose file.

But you can use the default value of the argument after `FROM`:

> To use the default value of an `ARG` declared before the first `FROM` use an `ARG` instruction without a value inside of a build stage. - [*from docker docs*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact)

```
ARG NODE_VERSION

FROM node:$NODE_VERSION

ARG HELLO

RUN echo "-> $HELLO"
RUN echo "-> $NODE_VERSION"
```

---

To use and show the node version defined in the arguments you need to rename this argument. So you can use the following to show all your arguments and the environment variable of the image:

**Dockerfile:**

```
ARG CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION

FROM node:$CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION

ARG CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION
ARG HELLO

RUN echo "-> $HELLO"               #output: 5
RUN echo "-> $NODE_VERSION"        #output: 8.9.4
RUN echo "-> $CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION" #output: 8
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3"

services:
  ei:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION: 8
        HELLO: 5
```

Comment: I am impressed at how well you explained this, bravo and thanks!

Comment: I made this mistake and have been banging my head against a wall for a day, before I thought to Google it. Your answer had my issue resolved in < 30 sec.

Comment: Wow this is amazing! I also encountered that even if we assigned the value explicitly in the beginning to the ARG in the DockerFile (for example: ARG CUSTOM_NODE_VERSION=8 in Line 1), it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 4):

In case you came here and your syntax and everything was fine, but the variable still wasn't passing through...

It may be the case that you're trying to override a variable that's already set by the parent image (in my case, trying to set `BUNDLE_PATH` which was already being set by the `ruby` parent image).

If this is the case, you can simply rename the argument to something that won't conflict with the parent (ie, instead of `BUNDLE_PATH`, use `ARG_BUNDLE_PATH`)!

```
ARG ARG_BUNDLE_PATH
ENV BUNDLE_PATH=$ARG_BUNDLE_PATH
```

See this issue for more details: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34494

Comment: I was stumped for a while and this saved me.  Thank you!

Comment: Awesome addition, that is the problem I had