# Docker-compose env var not working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to set env var in my docker compose file but the var does not seems to propagate to my docker.

my docker-compose:

```
test:
  build: ./
  environment:
    TESTVAR: "YOU ARE BEST"
```

my dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine

RUN echo test variable is: $TESTVAR
```

outputs:

```
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine
 ---> 3fd9065eaf02
Step 2/2 : RUN echo test variable is $TESTVAR
 ---> Running in d5f5505b26db
test variable is
Removing intermediate container d5f5505b26db
 ---> a9c019ac7eff
Successfully built a9c019ac7eff
Successfully tagged phpfpm_test:latest
Recreating phpfpm_test_1 ... done
Attaching to phpfpm_test_1
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Note:** If your service specifies a build option, variables defined in environment are not automatically visible during the build. Use the [`args`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args) sub-option of build to define build-time environment variables. - [from docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment)

So you can use arguments ([`args`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args)) instead of environment ([`environment`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment)):

**Docker Compose (v2 or v3)**:

```
version: '2'  # or 3
services:
  test:
    build: 
      context: ./
    args:
      TESTVAR: 'YOU ARE BEST'
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM alpine
ARG TESTVAR

RUN echo "test variable is: $TESTVAR"
```

**Requirements:**

- *Docker Compose*: 1.6.0+
- *Docker Engine*: 1.10.0+

---

**Note:** You need to define the argument (`ARG TESTVAR`) after the `FROM` to use the value specified on docker-compose file ([more info on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831447/docker-compose-build-args-not-passing-to-dockerfile/48833083#48833083)).

Comment: What about when I use image instead build option when defining my service?

Answer (score -2):

You can use .env file in the same directory of docker-compose file , works for me