# Pass variables from .env file to dockerfile through docker-compose

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, docker-compose, dockerfile

```
project
└───app
│   │   ...
│   │   Dockerfile
│   │
└───prod.env
└───docker-compose.yml
```

My docker-compose looks like this:

```
services:
   app:
      build:
         context: .\app
         args:
            ARG1: val1
            ARG2: val2
      env_file:
         - prod.env
```

But I've tried this too:

```
services:
   app:
      build:
         context: .\app
         args:
            ARG1: ${ARG1}
            ARG2: ${ARG2}
      env_file:
         - prod.env
```

My prod.env file looks like this:

```
ARG1 = 'val1'
ARG2 = 'val2'
```

But I've tried this too:

```
ARG1=val1
ARG2=val2
```

I would like for either the values of args or the values from the prod.env file to be passed to the dockerfile.

This is what I've tried to get this:

```
ARG ARG1
ARG ARG2

RUN echo ${ARG1}
RUN echo ${ARG2}
```

```
ENV ARG1 ${ARG1}
ENV ARG2 ${ARG2}

RUN echo ${ARG1}
RUN echo ${ARG2}
```

```
ENV ARG1 "new val2"
ENV ARG2 "new val2"

RUN echo ${ARG1}
RUN echo ${ARG2}
```

It always end with blank values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I feel like no answers from other posts have worked when I tried them.

To build I use `docker-compose --env-file prod.env build`

Thanks

**Update**
Sergio Santiago asked if I could run `docker-compose config` and show the results.

Here are the final files I used for this test.

docker-compose:

```
services:
   app:
      build:
         context: .\app
         args:
            ARG1: val1
            ARG2: val2
      env_file:
         - prod.env
```

prod.env:

```
ARG3 = 'val3'
ARG4 = 'val4'
```

And here is the output of `docker-compose --env-file prod.env config`

```
networks:
  demo-net: {}
services:
  app:
    build:
      args:
        ARG1: val1
        ARG2: val2
      context: C:\project\app
    environment:
      ENV: prod.env
      ARG3: val3
      ARG4: val4
```

I would like to add that clearly from here getting the variable from the .env file to the docker-compose file is not the issue. I also have a flask app running on the container and through os.environ it is able to use the variables in the .env file. I just can't figure out how to give the same access to the Dockerfile.

**Update 2**
More specific information in relation to ErikMD's answer

prod.env

```
DOMAIN = 'actualdomain.com'
ENV = 'prod.env'
ENV_NUM = 1
ARG1 = 'value1'
```

dev.env

```
DOMAIN = 'localhost'
ENV = 'dev.env'
ENV_NUM = 0
ARG1 = 'value1'
```

Notice that the value for ARG1 is the same but the other values are different.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  home:
    image: home-${ENV_NUM}
    build: 
      context: .\home
      args:
        ARG1: "${ARG1}"
    networks:
      - demo-net
    env_file:
      - ${ENV}
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.home.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.home.entrypoints=web
    volumes:
      - g:\:c:\sharedrive
...
...
  reverse-proxy:
    restart: always
    image: traefik:v2.6.1-windowsservercore-1809
    command:
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --entrypoints.web.address=:80
      - --providers.docker.endpoint=npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
     - demo-net
    volumes:
      - source: \\.\pipe\docker_engine\
        target: \\.\pipe\docker_engine\
        type: npipe
networks:
  demo-net:
```

The dots represent other apps that would be formatted the same as home.

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10.3

ARG ARG1="default"

ENV ARG1="${ARG1}"

WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN echo "This is argument 1 -> ${ARG1}"
```

output of `docker-compose --env-file prod.env config`

```
networks:
  demo-net: {}
services:
  home:
    build:
      args:
        ARG1: value1
      context: C:\MIS-Web-App\home
    environment:
      DOMAIN: actualdomain.com
      ENV: prod.env
      ENV_NUM: '1'
      ARG1: value1
    image: home-1
    labels:
      traefik.enable: "true"
      traefik.http.routers.home.entrypoints: web
      traefik.http.routers.home.rule: Host(`mis.canaras.net`)
    networks:
      demo-net: null
    volumes:
    - g:\:c:\sharedrive:rw
...
...
```

Then I run either `docker-compose --env-file prod.env build` or `docker-compose --env-file dev.env build`

output of build

```
Step 9/23 : RUN echo "This is argument 1 -> ${ARG1}"
 ---> Running in 5142850de365
This
is
argument
1
->
Removing intermediate container 5142850de365
```

Now I call pass the env_file in the command as well as in the actual file because there are variables in there that my docker-compose file needs and variables that my flask app needs. And there is definitely overlap.

Getting the values from the prod.env or dev.env files to docker-compose is not the issue. Neither is getting it to my flask app. The issue is getting those values to the dockerfile.

Comment: Could you please update your question with the output of `docker-compose config`

Comment: @SergioSantiago Thanks for the comment. I added the output to the question.

Comment: This should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/48833083/1563297

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker-compose build args not passing to Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831447/docker-compose-build-args-not-passing-to-dockerfile)

Comment: @SergioSantiago Yes this makes sense, but is it the best method. I am already passing the variable from the .env file. So does that mean in the docker-compose file I have to define args and pass it the value from the env file? Or is there a way to just grab the value from the env file that is being passed in environment? For example, in my updated files shown above, is there a way to get the values of ARG3 and ARG4 without changing the docker-compose file?

Comment: @ErikMD Thank you for sharing as well. I would've mentioned you both in the comment above if I was allowed to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution was annoying which is why it took me so long to figure it out.
My dockerfile was using powershell on a windows server, so I had to do this for every argument:

```
ARG ARG1
RUN echo $env:ARG1
```

This seems pretty niche especially since using windows containers on a windows server is not my first choice, so check out @ErikMD 's answer if your having issues with env files and whatnot.

Comment: Indeed, good point… so I believe it's worth it to add the [tag:windows] and [tag:powershell] tags in your original question. I'm going to do it right away, but let me know if you disagree, or want to replace one tag with [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/tags). (You can also [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72092982/edit) your own question and directly change the tags of course.)

Answer (score 7):

I'm posting a new answer to highlight the various assumptions related to the OP's question, in particular, the fact that there's a subtle difference between the `".env"` unique filename and `*.env` files (arguments for `env_file:`).

But apart from this subtlety, the process to pass arguments from `docker-compose.yml` to `docker build -f Dockerfile .` and/or `docker run -e …` is easy, as shown by the comprehensive example below.

#### Minimal working example

Let's consider the following files in a given directory, say `./docker`.

File `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  demo-1:
    image: demo-${ENV_NUM}
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        ARG1: "demo-1/${ARG1}"
        ARG3: "demo-1/${ARG3}"
  demo-2:
    image: demo-2${ENV_FILE_NUM}
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        ARG1: "demo-2/${ARG1}"
        ARG3: "demo-2/${ARG3}"
    env_file:
      - var.env
```

**Remark:** even if we use a `build:` field, it appears to be a good idea to also add an `image:` field to automatically tag the built image; but note that these image names must be pairwise different.

File `.env`:

```ini
KEY="some value"
ENV_NUM=1
ARG1=.env/ARG1
ARG2=.env/ARG2
ARG3=.env/ARG3
```

File `var.env`:

```ini
ENV_FILE_NUM="some number"
ARG1=var.env/ARG1
ARG2=var.env/ARG2
ARG3=var.env/ARG3
ARG4=var.env/ARG4
```

File `Dockerfile`:

```docker
FROM debian:10

# Read build arguments (default value if omitted at CLI)
ARG ARG1="default 1"
ARG ARG2="default 2"
ARG ARG3="default 3"

# the build args are exported at build time
RUN echo "ARG1=${ARG1}" | tee /root/arg1.txt
RUN echo "ARG2=${ARG2}" | tee /root/arg2.txt
RUN echo "ARG3=${ARG3}" | tee /root/arg3.txt

# Export part of these args at runtime also
ENV ARG1="${ARG1}"
ENV ARG2="${ARG2}"

# exec-form is mandatory for ENTRYPOINT/CMD
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo ARG1=\"${ARG1}\" ARG2=\"${ARG2}\" ARG3=\"${ARG3}\"; echo while at build time:; cat /root/arg{1,2,3}.txt"]
```

#### Experiment session 1

First, [as suggested by @SergioSantiago in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72092982/pass-variables-from-env-file-to-dockerfile-through-docker-compose/72105118#comment127382372_72092982), a very handy command to preview the effective `docker-compose.yml` file after interpolation is [`docker-compose config`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/config/):

```bash
$ docker-compose config

WARN[0000] The "ENV_FILE_NUM" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
name: docker
services:
  demo-1:
    build:
      context: /home/debian/docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ARG1: demo-1/.env/ARG1
        ARG3: demo-1/.env/ARG3
    image: demo-1
    networks:
      default: null
  demo-2:
    build:
      context: /home/debian/docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        ARG1: demo-2/.env/ARG1
        ARG3: demo-2/.env/ARG3
    environment:
      ARG1: var.env/ARG1
      ARG2: var.env/ARG2
      ARG3: var.env/ARG3
      ARG4: var.env/ARG4
      ENV_FILE_NUM: some number
    image: demo-2
    networks:
      default: null
networks:
  default:
    name: docker_default
```

Here, as indicated by the warning, we see there's an issue for interpolating `ENV_FILE_NUM` despite the fact this variable is mentioned by `var.env`. The reason is that **`env_file`s** lines just add new environment variables for the underlying `docker run -e …` command, but **don't interpolate anything** in the `docker-compose.yml`.

Contrarily, one can notice that the value `ARG1=.env/ARG1` taken from **`".env"`** is interpolated within the `args:` field of `docker-compose.yml`, cf. the output line:

```yaml
args:
  ARG1: demo-1/.env/ARG1
  …
```

This very distinct semantics of `".env"` vs. `env_file`s is described in [this page of the official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file).

#### Experiment session 2

Next, let us run:

```bash
$ docker-compose up --build
                                                                                         
WARN[0000] The "ENV_FILE_NUM" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.                                                                     
[+] Building 10.4s (13/13) FINISHED
 => [demo-1 internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
 => => transferring dockerfile: 609B
 => [demo-2 internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
 => => transferring dockerfile: 609B
 => [demo-1 internal] load .dockerignore
 => => transferring context: 2B
 => [demo-2 internal] load .dockerignore
 => => transferring context: 2B
 => [demo-2 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:10
 => [demo-2 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/debian:10@sha256:ebe4b9831fb22dfa778de4ffcb8ea0ad69b5d782d4e86cab14cc1fded5d8e761
 => => resolve docker.io/library/debian:10@sha256:ebe4b9831fb22dfa778de4ffcb8ea0ad69b5d782d4e86cab14cc1fded5d8e761
 => => sha256:85bed84afb9a834cf090b55d2e584abd55b4792d93b750db896f486680638344 50.44MB / 50.44MB
 => => sha256:ebe4b9831fb22dfa778de4ffcb8ea0ad69b5d782d4e86cab14cc1fded5d8e761 1.85kB / 1.85kB
 => => sha256:40dd1c1b1c36eac161ab63b6ce3a57d56ad79a667a37717a31721bac3f30aaf9 529B / 529B
 => => sha256:26a2b081e03207d26a105340161109ba0f00e857cbb0ff85aaeeeadd46b709c5 1.46kB / 1.46kB
 => => extracting sha256:85bed84afb9a834cf090b55d2e584abd55b4792d93b750db896f486680638344
 => [demo-2 2/4] RUN echo "ARG1=demo-2/.env/ARG1" | tee /root/arg1.txt
 => [demo-1 2/4] RUN echo "ARG1=demo-1/.env/ARG1" | tee /root/arg1.txt
 => [demo-1 3/4] RUN echo "ARG2=default 2" | tee /root/arg2.txt
 => [demo-2 3/4] RUN echo "ARG2=default 2" | tee /root/arg2.txt
 => [demo-2 4/4] RUN echo "ARG3=demo-2/.env/ARG3" | tee /root/arg3.txt
 => [demo-1 4/4] RUN echo "ARG3=demo-1/.env/ARG3" | tee /root/arg3.txt
 => [demo-2] exporting to image
 => => exporting layers
 => => writing image sha256:553f294a410ceeb3c0ac9d252d443710c804d3f7437ad7fffa586967517f5e7a
 => => naming to docker.io/library/demo-1
 => => writing image sha256:84bb2bd0ffae67ffed0e74efbf9253b6d634a6f37c6f99bc4eedea81846a9352
 => => naming to docker.io/library/demo-2
                                     
Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
[+] Running 3/3              
 ⠿ Network docker_default     Created
 ⠿ Container docker-demo-1-1  Created
 ⠿ Container docker-demo-2-1  Created
```

```
Attaching to docker-demo-1-1, docker-demo-2-1

docker-demo-1-1  | ARG1=demo-1/.env/ARG1 ARG2=default 2 ARG3=
docker-demo-1-1  | while at build time:
docker-demo-1-1  | ARG1=demo-1/.env/ARG1
docker-demo-1-1  | ARG2=default 2
docker-demo-1-1  | ARG3=demo-1/.env/ARG3

docker-demo-2-1  | ARG1=var.env/ARG1 ARG2=var.env/ARG2 ARG3=var.env/ARG3
docker-demo-2-1  | while at build time:
docker-demo-2-1  | ARG1=demo-2/.env/ARG1
docker-demo-2-1  | ARG2=default 2
docker-demo-2-1  | ARG3=demo-2/.env/ARG3

docker-demo-1-1 exited with code 0
docker-demo-2-1 exited with code 0
```

Here, we can see again that the `".env"` values and those of `file_env: [ filename.env ]` play different roles that don't overlap.

Furthermore:

- Given the absence of a Dockerfile command line `ENV ARG3="${ARG3}"`, the value of build-arg `ARG3` is not propagated at runtime (see the `ARG3=` line in the output above).
- But the value can be exported at runtime anyway if it is defined/overidden in the `environment:` or `env_file:` sections in the `docker-compose.yml` file (see the `ARG3=var.env/ARG3` line in the output above).

For more details, see the documentation of the [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) directive.

#### Remarks on the `docker-compose --env-file` option use-case

As mentioned by the OP, `docker-compose` also enjoys a useful CLI option `--env-file` (which is precisely named the same way as the very different `env-file:` field, which is unfortunate, but nevermind).

This option allows for the following use-case (excerpt from OP's code):

File `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  home:
    image: home-${ENV_NUM}
    build:
      args:
        ARG1: "${ARG1}"
      ...
    labels:
      - traefik.http.routers.home.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN}`)
      ...
    env_file:
      - ${ENV}
```

File `prod.env`:

```ini
DOMAIN = 'actualdomain.com'
ENV = 'prod.env'
ENV_NUM = 1
ARG1 = 'value 1'
```

File `dev.env`:

```ini
DOMAIN = 'localhost'
ENV = 'dev.env'
ENV_NUM = 0
ARG1 = 'value 1'
```

Then run:

- `docker-compose --env-file prod.env build`,
- or `docker-compose --env-file dev.env build`

As an aside, even if most of this answer up to now, amounted to illustrating that the `".env"` filename and `env_file:` files enjoy a very different semantics… it is true that they can also be combined "nicely" this way, as suggested by the OP, to achieve this use case.

Note in passing that the **`docker-compose config`** is also applicable to "debug" the Compose specification:

- `docker-compose --env-file prod.env config`,
- or `docker-compose --env-file dev.env config`.

Now regarding the last question:

> Getting the values from the `prod.env` or `dev.env` files to `docker-compose` is not the issue. The issue is getting those values to the `Dockerfile`.

it can first be noted that there are two different cases:

1. Either the two different deployment environments (`prod.env` and `dev.env`) can share the same image, so that the difference only lies in the **runtime environment variables** (not the **docker build args**).
2. Or, depending on the file passed for `--env-file`, the images should be different (and then a `docker-compose --env-file … build` is indeed necessary).

It appears that most of the time, case 1. can be achieved (and it is also the case in the question's configuration, because the `ARG1` values are the same in `prod.env` and `dev.env`) and can be viewed as more-interesting for the sake of reproducibility (because we are sure that the "prod" image will be the same as the "dev" image).

Yet, sometimes it's impossible to do so and we are "in case 2.", e.g. if the `Dockerfile` has a specific step, maybe related to tests or so, that has to be enabled (resp. disabled) in production mode.

So now, let us assume we're in case 2. How can we pass "everything" from the `--env-file` to the `Dockerfile`? There is only one solution, namely, extending the `args:` map of the `docker-compose.yml` and include each variable you are interested in, for example:

```yaml
services:
  home:
    image: home-${ENV_NUM}
    build: 
      context: .\home
      args:
        DOMAIN: "${DOMAIN}"
        ENV_NUM: "${ENV_NUM}"
        ARG1: "${ARG1}"
    networks:
      - demo-net
    env_file:
      - ${ENV}
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.http.routers.home.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.home.entrypoints=web
    volumes:
      - g:\:c:\sharedrive
```

Even if there is no other solution to pass arguments at build time (from `docker-compose` to the underlying `docker build -f Dockerfile …`), this has the advantage of being "declarative" (only the variables mentioned in `args:` will be actually passed to the `Dockerfile`).

#### Drawback?

The only drawback I see is that you may have unneeded extra environment variables at runtime (from `docker-compose` to the underlying `docker run -e …`), such as `ENV=prod.env`.

If this is an issue, you might want to split your `".env"` files like this:

File `prod.env`:

```ini
DOMAIN = 'actualdomain.com'
ENV = 'prod-run.env'
ENV_NUM = 1
ARG1 = 'value 1'
```

File `prod-run.env`:

```ini
DOMAIN = 'actualdomain.com'
ENV_NUM = 1
```

(assuming you only want to export these two environment variables at runtime).

Or alternatively, to better follow the usual *Do-not-Repeat-Yourself* rule, **remove `prod-run.env`**, then pass these values as `docker-compose` build arguments as mentioned previously:

```yaml
args:
  DOMAIN: "${DOMAIN}"
  ENV_NUM: "${ENV_NUM}"
```

**and** write in the `Dockerfile`:

```docker
ARG DOMAIN
ARG ENV_NUM

# ... and in the end:

ENV DOMAIN="${DOMAIN}"
ENV ENV_NUM="${ENV_NUM}"
```

I already gave an example of these `Dockerfile` directives in section **"Experiment session 2".**

(Sorry for the significant length of this answer BTW :)

Comment: Hi, Erik. Thanks for putting this together. There may still be a misunderstanding that I wanted to clarify so I added another update to the question. I would like to reiterate what I say at the end of that update. And that is getting the values from the prod.env or dev.env files to docker-compose is not the issue. The issue is getting those values to the dockerfile. It seems like from what you said it may not be possible with an env_file, but I also pass the file using --env-file in the command.

Comment: Hi @ceejpie, thanks for your feedback! Indeed I guess what you intended to do is feasible… I've extended my answer to better address your question after your last edit.

Comment: Hey, Erik. This was some great stuff. Very helpful all around. Apparently I'm too new to upvote unfortunately. However, my issues were solved by the solution I shared. Windows has given me many issues during this whole process, so I should've realized this would be the same. For some reason I didn't think the operating system would make a difference for this issue. Thanks and cheers

Comment: OK thanks for your comment! Glad that you figured out a solution for your windows/docker environment! And it is indeed documented one cannot vote on questions before [15 rep.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), but it may already be possible for you to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) an answer (either yours or mine), to indicate that your question has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Another, albeit niche, solution that lets you dynamically pass all the variables from a .env file to the Dockerfile build environment through compose is via a multistage Dockerfile. Copy the file, use it and copy only the result to the second stage.

Passing the path of `dev.env` to `web/Dockerfile` as the only arg in the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: builders
      dockerfile: web/Dockerfile
      no_cache: true
      args:
        - ENV_FILE=dev.env
    env_file:
      - builders/dev.env
...
```

First stage of `web/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim

ARG ENV_FILE

WORKDIR /PB

COPY /$ENV_FILE $ENV_FILE

RUN pip install --upgrade pip python-dotenv

RUN pip install  --no-cache-dir --upgrade python-dotenv

COPY code/prebuild.py prebuild.py

COPY static old/static

RUN python3 prebuild.py $ENV_FILE
```

The relevant portion of `prebuild.py`:

```
import sys
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv(sys.argv[1])
```

Following the python script's injection of needed variables, the second stage of `web/Dockerfile` copies the updated static files to the final image:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY /web/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY --from=0 /PB/static/ /web/static/
```

The last line's `--from=0` tells docker to pull `/PB/static/` from the first stage.

The full multistage `web/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim

ARG ENV_FILE

WORKDIR /PB

COPY /$ENV_FILE $ENV_FILE

RUN pip install --upgrade pip python-dotenv

RUN pip install  --no-cache-dir --upgrade python-dotenv

COPY code/prebuild.py prebuild.py

COPY static old/static

RUN python3 prebuild.py $ENV_FILE

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY /web/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY --from=0 /PB/static/ /web/static/
```

My specific use-case already involved a multipart Dockerfile running a python script to inject certain environmental variables, such as the development/production API domains, into the static files of a site so it worked well for me, but you're mileage may vary. It's also worth noting that the environmental variables and the .env file itself won't be accessible in the second stage of the Dockerfile.

Comment: this is a smart workaround!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.env file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file) from docker compose so you use the same time that you defined in your service definition:

```
services:
    app:
         build:
            context: .\app
            args:
               ARG1: ${ARG3}
               ARG2: ${ARG4}
         env_file:
            - .env
```

In this way both can share the same env file, but you still have the drawback of redefining the variables as a placeholder.

This is a suggestion, choose the one that fits better to you

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea — naming an `env_file` as `".env"`, as this latter name is a special filename… cf. https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file