# Cannot pass a variable to the volumes section in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file that defines the volumes section like this:

```
volumes:
  seqfs:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: seqtest
      storage_account_name: stacctest
      storage_account_key: ${STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY}
```

I am trying to pass in STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY during the build command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build --build-arg STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY="##########"
```

But an error is returned:

**The STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.**

Please note I do not want to save STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY into a file such as .env for security reasons -- I want to pass it from the command line.

How can I pass an argument to the volumes section in my docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Volumes are only used at run-time. I recommend building using `docker build` and only use docker-compose to create your run-time environment. That makes it clearer what it available when, imo.

Answer (score 0):

### Regarding the error you get:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml build --build-arg STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY="##########"

But an error is returned:

The STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

- the fact is that `--build-arg` only deals with **`ARG`** directives within the Dockerfile.
- (BTW it is simpler to run `docker-compose up --build`
  rather than running `docker-compose build` *then* `docker-compose up`)
- the only solutions I can think about to achieve what you want are:

1. either put `STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY=foobar` in an `.env` file
   and run `docker-compose up --build`
2. or put `STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY=foobar` in an `other.env` file
   and run `docker-compose --env-file=other.env up --build`

   (**Note:** the docker/compose syntax contains two different kinds of `"env-file"`, for details on this subtlety, see [this answer of mine: Pass variables from .env file to dockerfile through docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72105572/9164010).)
3. or run `STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY=foobar docker-compose up --build`

### Concluding remarks:

You said you *do not want to save STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY into a file such as .env for security reasons*, so at first sight you would only accept solution 3. above.

However, note that it is unlikely that 3. is more secure if you assume you don't trust the environment of your docker host. Indeed, `.env` files may be protected thanks to file permissions (and `.gitignore` FWIW), while the `foobar` string above automatically leaks in the name of the running processes (try e.g. `ps aux | grep STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY`).

Comment: @user1044169 did you get a chance to test my suggestion(s)?