# Docker Compose file seen as invalid when using variable interpolation

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  myapp_db:
    image: mysql:5.8
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env.local
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQLDB_DATABASE
    ports:
      - $MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  db:
```

And the following `.env.local` file:

```
MYSQLDB_USER=root
MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
MYSQLDB_DATABASE=myapp_db_local
MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT=3307
MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT=3306
```

When I run `docker-compose start` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.myapp_db.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
```

**Where am I going awry?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Origin of the issue

The culprit of the error is the `env_file: ./.env.local` field that does not have the meaning you had in mind.

Namely, `env_file:` only means: add each pair (`MYSQLDB_USER`, `root`) from the specified env file as extra environment variables, as if you had written:

```yaml
environment:
  MYSQLDB_USER: "root"
  # etc.
```

As a result, no interpolation occurred in the YAML file itself, and you got:

```yaml
ports:
  - :
```

#### What to do then?

To sum up, what you want is to **interpolate variables everywhere** in `docker-compose.yml`.

To achieve so, no annotation is possible/required.

Just an extra CLI argument:

- `docker-compose --env-file .env.local up -d`
- I recommend you also try: **`docker-compose --env-file .env.local config`** [(cf. doc)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_config/)

Note also that if your env file is named `.env`, no CLI argument `--env-file .env` is necessary, because **the special file `.env` is always interpolated** by Docker Compose.

And for more details on the subtleties of `env_file:` vs. `--env-file`, see also this older answer of mine: [Pass variables from .env file to dockerfile through docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72105572/9164010)

Comment: Also FWIW `mysql:5.8` was invalid. Stepping it down to `mysql:5.7` also allowed it to run with your (very helpful!) commands up above.

Comment: BTW note that `version: "3.8"` is now unnecessary in the latest [*Compose Specification*](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/), which is recommended over 2.x and 3.x `docker-compose.yml` specs

Comment: See in particular: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#versioning