# Docker Compose unable to replace the variables from env file

Tags: docker, github, docker-compose, github-actions

This is my current process. I build my application images on github and store them as a package. My variables are set in an env file stored next to my docker-compose file. I then copy my docker-compose file onto the server and then enter:

> docker-compose -f ../repo/sdr_app/docker-dev-sdr_core-be-compose.yml
> up -d

This then downloads my images from github and it is supposed to do variable replacement? in my appsettings.json file.

However, during the compose stage, I get multiple errors saying that all my variables were not set and are defaulting to a blank string.

> Example: err: The SDR_APP_CONNECTIONSTRING variable is not set.
> Defaulting to a blank string.

What am I missing from my docker compose file?

My docker compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  be_nginx:
    environment:
      - TZ:"Asia/Singapore"
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
    - ../repo/sdr_app/.env-docker-dev
    networks: 
    - ${SDR_NETWORK}
    volumes:
      - ./be_nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt:ro
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot:ro
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"

  sdr_app.api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Docker_Dev_DO
      - TZ=Asia/Singapore
      - APP_ID=${APP_ID}
      - SDR_APP_CONNECTIONSTRING=${SDR_APP_CONNECTIONSTRING}
      - FILE_CACHE_IN_SECONDS=${FILE_CACHE_IN_SECONDS}
      - DEPLOY_ORIGIN=${DEPLOY_ORIGIN}
    image: loca.io/uone/sdr_app.api:latest
    env_file:
    - ../repo/sdr_app/.env-docker-dev
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: SDR_App.Api/Dockerfile
    networks: 
    - ${SDR_NETWORK}
    volumes:
    - "../dev.repo/:/app-volumes/"
    - "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro"
    - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
 
networks:
  core-network:
      name: ${SDR_NETWORK}
```

This is my env file:

```
SDR_NETWORK=core-network
COMPOSE_IGNORE_ORPHANS=True
SDR_APP_CONNECTIONSTRING=abcdefg
```

I ran this command docker-compose -f ../repo/sdr_app/docker-dev-sdr_core-be-compose.yml config

but I discovered that not all variables were filled up. I also had multiple warnings where the variable is not set.

Im not sure why.

Comment: I guess when you say "This is my env file:", you meant "this is the contents of file `../repo/sdr_app/.env-docker-dev`", in which case the issue is an exact duplicate of [Docker Compose file seen as invalid when using variable interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75538300/9164010).

Comment: To sum up: `env_file:` does **NOT** provide *interpolation*, but `docker run`-based *environment variables*. Instead, you should use `docker-compose --env-file ../repo/sdr_app/.env-docker-dev -f ../repo/sdr_app/docker-dev-sdr_core-be-compose.yml config`.

Comment: For details on this subtle distinction (`env_file:` vs. `--env-file`), see also [this longer answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72105572/9164010).